# c++ custom button icon

Tags: c++, winapi

I would like to make a button with dynamic width.
Here is my code:

```
CreateWindowEx(BS_PUSHBUTTON, "BUTTON", "OK",
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
            50, 220, 100, 24, hwnd,
            (HMENU)ID_BUTTON,
            GetModuleHandle(NULL),
            0);
```

But if I change the label "OK" to "SOMETHING LONGER", then the button is not wide enough.
How can I set dynamic width?

Comment: [AdjustWindowRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632665(v=vs.85).aspx), [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx), [MoveWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633534(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Button_GetIdealSize macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761851%28VS.85%29.aspx).

---

OK, David, please next time supply more information, mention everything you don't understand, because from your questions in comments I can infer that you are not only unfamiliar with Win API, but you are also very new to the C/C++ programming in general.

```
HWND buttonHandle = CreateWindowEx(BS_PUSHBUTTON, "BUTTON", "OK",
                                   WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
                                   50, 220, 100, 24,
                                   hwnd,
                                   (HMENU)ID_BUTTON,
                                   GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                                   0);
SIZE size;

if (!Button_GetIdealSize(buttonHandle, &size)) {
  // Call of `Button_GetIdealSize` failed, do proper error handling here.
  // For that you have various options:
  // 1. Exit current scope and return error code;
  // 2. Throw an exception;
  // 3. Terminate execution of your application and print an error message.
  // Of course these options can be mixed.
  // If you don't understand what I'm talking about here, then either skip this
  // check or start reading books on software development with C/C++.
}

// At this point `size` variable was filled with proper dimensions.
// Now we can use it to actually resize our button...

if (!MoveWindow(buttonHandle, 50, 220, (int)size.cx, (int)size.cy, TRUE)) {
  // Call of `MoveWindow` failed, do proper error handling here, again.
}

// We are done!
```

**NOTE**: The title of your question is incorrectly posed. C++ has nothing to do with buttons and Win API in particular, which is pure C by the way. Much better title would be: **Win API: How to properly resize a button to fit its contents?**

Comment: I think the documentation states it clear how to use it. The macro takes 2 parameters: a handle to the button and a pointer to `SIZE` structure, which will be filled with proper dimensions when the macro is invoked. So, when you called `CreateWindowEx` it returned you a handle to the newly created button. Now pass this handle into `Button_GetIdealSize` as the documentation states. As soon as you obtain the size from this macro, you can use [MoveWindow function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633534(v=vs.85).aspx) to resize the button.

Comment: BOOL Button_GetIdealSize(
  HWND hwnd,
  SIZE *pSize
);
How can I get the pSize?

Comment: Sorry. I thought that will be enough information.
I use eclipse+minGW and I have to define somehow the Button_GetIdealSize(). But what I have to include?

Comment: David, please, pay attention to the documentation. If you go to the [Button_GetIdealSize macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761851%28VS.85%29.aspx) again and scroll down you will notice the summary table. The last row of it states that the header you need to include is called `Commctrl.h`.

Comment: In the mingw--commctrl.h doesnt contain the Button_GetIdealSize()
here is the commctrl.h: http://gitorious.org/mingw/mingw-w32api/blobs/240e5bbe9b18a18f3c975ba5ac923a4c537f3bb6/include/commctrl.h

Comment: My MinGW-w64 distribution contains it exactly in `commctrl.h`: `#define Button_GetIdealSize(hwnd,psize) (WINBOOL)SNDMSG((hwnd),BCM_GETIDEALSIZE,0,(LPARAM)(psize))
`. Your MinGW distribution might be out-dated. You should use [MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/), rather than MinGW, because it is more mature and is actively developed. In addition, it has support for building 64-bit targets. I think, you've got an exhaustive answer to your initial question. If you seek for more information not related to your original question, then you should create another question.

Comment: [Proof](http://mingw-w64.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/mingw-w64/trunk/mingw-w64-headers/include/commctrl.h?revision=5663&view=markup) - line 4339.

Comment: Thanks! I updated to minGW-w64 and it builds succesfully! But the result is an empty window, I think the size filled with 0.

Comment: Well, check it with debugger or by printing them, and tell me what's going on. Did you check for failures as in the example I provided?

Comment: @David, if my answer was helpful to you, then you could consider accepting it. [How do I ask questions here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) - might be worth reading for you too.